# CCTV plugin not loading in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cctv

We use Vivotek CCTVs, and we need to view the video stream in our browser.

I have a problem with one our offices' CCTVs in Firefox. I think I blocked the website plugin from running on this site, so the video does not stream. It streams on all other sites in Firefox.

I've reset Firefox, and the issue remains.

If I right-click, view page info > Permissions, the plugin I believe I need to get working is called "npWinLessRtspCtrl", and this was set to "Use default". I set it to "Allow", restarted the browser, and the issue remains - the video player is solid grey.

If I close the browser, I get a message saying the plugin is busy, asking if I want to stop it, so it appears the permission might be correct.

Unfortunately IE & Chrome are not loading any CCTV video streams, so I'd like to get Firefox working on this remaining problem site.

Not sure where to go from here. Help appreciated.

Comment: Is the camera actually working? What version of FF are you using?

Comment: Did you try with a new Firefox profile? [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)

Comment: @steve any update on whether you were able to resolve the issue. I am facing the same issue the `npwinlessrtspctrl` is not allowed by firefox some how.

Comment: Hi @Krishna_Oza - I can't remember unfortunately, this problem occurred at my last work place :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use IE, go to Tools > Internet options > Security > Custom Level. And allow the active X options in that, Then you will be able to see the streams.